# “Cannot preview in this file - Connection interrupted: send previewInstances message to agent" error in Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I've got a UIKit project and I'm slowly trying to move to SwiftUI, I created a SwiftUI file and I tried to preview it but I'm getting this error:

> Cannot preview in this file - Connection interrupted: send previewInstances message to agent

This is my SwiftUI File:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LineChart: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct LineChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LineChart()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

I only saw one similar question on StackOverFlow but that didn't help either, is there anyway that I could fix this? Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Hard to help here since it's not reproducible for anyone but you. Have you clicked Diagnostics and/or checked for any crash logs in the Console app

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, this is the Diagnostics report: ```MessageSendingError: Connection interrupted: send previewInstances message to agent```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Do you know how I could just run this in the simulator?

Comment: Not from a UIKit project but that information shouldn't be hard to find I assume

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal Have you tried cleaning the project & restarting Xcode? (the usual for non-reproducible Xcode problems )

Comment: @George_E Yes, did that soo many times, didn't work. :(

Comment: I found a fix here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6574#issuecomment-701427375

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal: could you please tell what was the fix?

Comment: For me, I got a similar error message `MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for send previewInstances message to agent`. It turned out the problem was I had recently made my Preview struct `private`, which apparently you can't do for the previews to work.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Not even the simplest SwiftUI view works, i.e. nothing is displayed in the canvas Preview. I have the error:

RemoteHumanReadableError: The request to open "com.apple.dt.XcodePreviews" failed.

Answer (score 10):

Turning off "Automatically Refresh Canvas" worked for me. (Xcode 13.2.1)

[image: Editor>Canvas>Automatically Refresh Canvas]

Answer (score 1):

Same error, seems that the automatically refresh canvas freeze the preview. Unchecking fixed the problem, but the whole sense of SwiftUI collapses without the automatic update.

Answer (score 1):

Same error. Changing simulator worked for me in Xcode 14.2!